# Prove that $\frac{1}{xy}\ge4$ given that $x+y=1$ and conclude that $(1+\frac1{x^2})(1+\frac1{y^2})\ge2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $x,y\in\mathbb R^+$ and $x+y=1$
>
> 1- Prove that $\frac{1}{xy}\ge4$
>
> 2- Conclude that $(1+\frac1{x^2})(1+\frac1{y^2})\ge25$

I have tried to start from $x+y=1$ or $x\ge0\land y\ge0$ and reach $\frac{1}{xy}\ge4$ but with no result.

**Update:**
I've proved the first part of the question (Thanks to Jack's comment).

Since the second question says "Conclude" that means I have to use the first proof. I tried to square the first proof and got it close to the second question, but
again no result. There is probably a trick that I don't know.

Comment: AM-GM: $\sqrt{xy}\leq\frac{x+y}{2}$.

Comment: There are two related problem in your Question.  Jack's suggestion helps (I suspect) tie them together, but the phrasing of the Question may focus the Readers attention on the first part.  It seems like a natural minimization by Calculus problem (in the first part).

Comment: @hardmath I rewrote the question. The question has nothing to do with calculus optimization (I guess). This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) helped me to answer the first part. Now I am still looking for an idea to solve the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x+y &=& 1 \\
x^2+2xy+y^2  &=& 1 \\
x^2-2xy+y^2  &=& 1-4xy \\
0 \leq (x-y)^2  &=&  1 -4xy.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rearrange and we have the desired inequality.

For the second part

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{y}\right)^2 \geq 0 \\
\frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{y^2} \geq \frac{2}{xy}
\end{eqnarray*}
So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
1+ \frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{y^2} + \left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)^2 \geq 1+ \frac{2}{xy}  + \left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)^2 =\left(1+\frac{1}{xy}\right)^2 \geq 25.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Given that $x+y=1$ means simply that the combination $(x,y)$ has to be a point on that line. Not above, not below, but ON the line.
With this condition the easiest thing to do is to graph: The ONLY point that is on both the line and on $\frac{1}{xy}=4$ is the point $(1/2,1/2)$ and this is the only solution that works. Perhaps you meant to ask "Solve $\frac{1}{xy}=4$,given that $x+y\geq1$?. Then the whole branch in the first quadrant would work. But as of now, it is just one single point

Answer (score 2):

given $X + Y = 1$, proof that $\frac{1}{XY} \ge 4$, where $X$ and $Y$ are real positive integers.
Since $X$ and $Y$ are positive integers then, $X \lt 1$ and $Y \lt 1$ for they to sum to $1$.
$X$ and $Y$ can be both equal 
So that $X + Y = 1$
this then becomes $X$ or $Y$ $= \frac{1}{2} = 0.5$
But if $X$ and $Y$ are distinct,
then
$
\begin{align}
X \gt 0.5 & and & Y \lt   0.5 & or\\
X \lt 0.5  &  and & Y \gt 0.5
\end{align}
$
Just depending of which is greater and lesser, for convenience let's assume $Y \gt X$.
So that a number $" a "$ must lie between both $X$ and $Y$

Such that....

$X = 0.5 - a$ and $Y = 0.5 + a$

where
$$
0 \le a \lt \frac{1}{2}
$$
because $X$ and $Y$ are positive integers.      So that the product of $X$ and  $Y$ is more pronounced as

$(0.5-a)×(0.5+a)$

which gives
$(0.5^2 - a^2)$
Therefore the inverse of there product
$\frac{1}{XY}$ becomes $\frac{1}{0.5^2 - a^2}$
Since $a \lt \frac{1}{2}$, $a$ runs from $\frac{1}{2}$ to approach $0$
         $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} - a^2}$
its maximum value is when $a$ approach $0$.                      $\frac{1}{0.25 - a^2}$

$\frac{1}{XY} \ge \frac{1}{0.25}$                                          $\frac{1}{XY} \ge 4$

Answer (score 2):

There's many answers here, but I'll post my answer here anyways; the proof essentially shows that even when some expression is the smallest it can be, the inequality still holds, which means it must necessarily always hold.

Given that $x+ y = 1$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$, show that $\frac{1}{xy} \ge 4$.

The *smallest* value $\frac{1}{xy}$ can have is when we have the largest value $xy$ can have. Now what is the largest possible value for $xy$? Change the given assumption to $y = 1-x$ and substitute into $xy$ to get $x-x^2$. We know that when the derivative of $x-x^2$ is $0$, then we have the max that we can have for $x$; $$f'(x-x^2) = 0$$ $$1-2x = 0$$ $$x = 0.5$$

If $x$ is $0.5$, then $y$ obviously is so as well because of $y = 1-x$.

This then means that $\frac{1}{xy}$ is it's smallest possible value when $x = y = 0.5$, and in that case it's $\frac{1}{0.5^2} = 4$.

Considering that we had the *smallest* possible value for the $LHS$ be $4$, it must necessarily be greater than or equal to the $RHS$ $4$.

---

Using the same logic, the second part follows easily. Substitute $y = 1-x$ into the fractions in the second part; we want the $LHS$ to be as small as possible, which means the two fractions added together needs to be as small as possible. This in turn means the denominators of the fractions, $x^2$ and $(1-x)^2$, needs to be as large as possible. Now we maximize $x^2 + (1-x)^2$ in the same way by taking the derivative and setting it to $0$:

$$f'(x + (1-x)^2) = 0$$
$$4x - 2 = 0$$
$$x = 0.5$$

So the *smallest* value that $(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})(1 + \frac{1}{y^2})$ can have is when $x = 0.5$, and similarly $y = 1-0.5 = 0.5$. Seeing what this gives us we get that $(1 + \frac{1}{0.5^2})(1 + \frac{1}{0.5^2}) = 25$, which of course is larger than $2$, considering that the smallest value the $LHS$ can have is $25$, the inequality must necessarily always hold.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

$(x-y)^2\geq 0$

$(x-y)^2 +4xy\geq 4xy $

$(x+y)^2\geq 4xy$

$1\geq 4xy$